# How to enumerate all webs and data in a SharePoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint, enumerate, spweb

What is the best way to enumerate all SPWebs in an SPSite and also to enumerate folders within document libraries within each of the SPWebs? (essentially I want to find out the urls of all SPWebs, and the number of folders and amount of data being stored in each).

I have achieved the above in C# using the SharePoint API but that takes a long time to run. It seems like the sort of thing that would be perfectly suited to an SQL query, but I understand that that wouldn't be recommended, but surely?! Does anyone have any SQL to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

Use of SQL queries, even for read-only is [unsupported](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikefitz/archive/2005/04/01/404802.aspx). For the read-only case this is because of locking. You *could* use NOLOCK but then your results aren't necessarily correct anyway so there's not much point.

I would schedule running the program you've already written overnight to generate a report for the following morning. Unfortunately there's really no better way to do it. You may like to make it a [timer job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686.aspx).

You may also want to look at a CodePlex tool called [SharePoint Usage Monitor](http://spusagemonitor.codeplex.com/) and/or products from major vendors that provide similar information. They all work the same way, to retrieve this data out-of-hours.

Comment: Doh, that's what I had suspected. It's not a good solution, but if it's the only one then I guess I've got to roll with it.